# Where is "dynamic help" feature in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net-framework, visual-studio

Where is "dynamic help" feature in **Visual Studio 2013**? I don't find any replacement of showing API when I click class name in source code.

Comment: Do you mean the Microsoft Hep Viewer 2.1 ?

Comment: The dynamic help is more than Microsoft Help of being a office help file. You can have dynamic help opened in frame. VS2013 will show class library when you click on variable in source code.

Comment: I just now of this in Visual Studio 2013: http://thirdblogfromthesun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/hv-splash-big.png

Comment: @Devid I have the same as you. I need to type class name and search it manually. If dynamic help is available, I only need to click the class in source code and the help page is already showing up.

I found this feature is removed:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/507561/bring-back-the-dynamic-help-in-visual-studio-2010